# Github how to rename the default branch from master to something else

Tags: github

I am using [github](https://github.com/) and would like to change the default branch from master to main branch.

Is there an easy way to do this from inside github site?.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have more than one branch ready

[image]

After that go to

Settings -> Branches

[image]

Open the drop down and select your branch name and press the Update button.